# Authorize POST endpoint with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've a REST endpoint in my Spring project `/public/signUser`; I want to authorize this endpoint without credentials in order to allow to create user. But if I try to do a `POST` request for `signUser` endpoint I received unauthorized error. I want to disable for this endpoint the authentication.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http .httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/signUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/hello", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .realmName("PlcManager")
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: i ve tried                 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/signUser").permitAll()
and                 .antMatchers("/public/hello", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
but not works

Comment: Can you remove HttpMethod.POST for while and test?